# How to slide in a specific div on specific anchor link click

Tags: jquery, html, animation, slider, slide

I have three anchor links that need to be triggers for a slider, and each anchor link has it's own div it corresponds with that's supposed to slide to the center of the screen once the anchor link for that div has been clicked.

And I need it to work that no matter which one is clicked on at the moment whichever anchor link is clicked next to slide that div to the center.

here is my html for the anchor links

```
<div class="main-slider">


<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="selector">
        <a id="slide-button-1">How Your Grow</a>
    </li>


    <li class="selector">
        <a id="slide-button-2">What You Need</a>

    </li>


    <li class="selector">
        <a id="slide-button-3">Who Needs It</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the html for each slide that I want to correspond to each anchor link

```
  <div class="slider-top">
     <div class="slider-bottom">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div id="slide-1"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="slide2"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="slide3"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have searched all over to find a solution to setting the different trigger buttons to slide the corresponding div to the center of the screen and all I've found is slider with 'previous' and next' buttons

thanks in advance for any help, greatly appreciated

Comment: What is in the div that "slides" to the center? Can the div just "appear"? Do you want it to be visible before it slides to the center, or should it be invisible? Can you give us your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information like the css and jQuery you are using it is very hard to answer, however typically I've found it the easiest to reposition divs by making them absolute or relative positioning and then animating the top or left value once you have one entered. From there you need to get close to the middle of the screen with some math or estimates. Check my jsfiddle or take a peek at the code below. Also I noticed you use a lot of ID#s I find it easier to use more .class when working with jquery so it's easier to remember what goes where when dealing with multiple moving items. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Holas/5wpjz/

```
    <div class="main-slider">
   <div class="slider-wrapper">
   <ul>
<li  class="selector1">
 <a href="#">How Your Grow</a>
</li>
 <li class="selector2">
 <a href="#">What You Need</a>
</li>
<li class="selector3">
<a href="#">Who Needs It</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

  <div class="slider-top">
 <div class="slider-bottom">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="slide1"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slide2"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slide3"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>         

$(".selector1").click(function () {
    $(".slide1").animate({"left": "+40%"}, "slow");
});


 $(".selector2").click(function () {
    $(".slide2").animate({"left": "+40%"}, "slow");
});

$(".selector3").click(function () {
    $(".slide3").animate({"left": "+40%"}, "slow");
});

ul, li , a{
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

.slide1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.slide2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: green;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.slide3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.selector {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Using this method you can position the divs offscreen and pull them in when the trigger button is clicked, and if they are positioned absolute you can even overlap them in the middle of the screen and order them with a z-index, going even further you can create a link or trigger button on each div to reverse the effect and the code will be pretty much the same.

Comment: Hey Holas, thanks for the response, yea this is a great start but I need a more refined function of jquery, and yea I know you need the css as well.. I added how I think the css could be here http://jsfiddle.net/Holas/5wpjz/ any thoughts with that?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what your going for, the jQuery is pretty much as refined as its going to get with with the problem as you proposed it as you have different links that move different items. It could be more refined if perhaps you wanted to have one div move around the page and just have the text or images change on that one div when a link is clicked but even then the changes would be minimal really.